# How to create a loop to evaluate a conditional function

Tags: python, math, physics

I am attempting to create a loop that will evaluate a function at discrete values. Normally this will be okay, however, this is proving to be difficult as my function is conditional (it has an adittional piecewise function which is dependent on the main variable.) This is an attempt I made below;

```
import math
import numpy as np

for i in np.arange(4000,8000,1000):
    def f(λ,a,u,o1,o2):
        o = o1 if (λ <= u) else o2
        return a*math.exp((λ-u)^2/(-2*o^2))
    print(f(i,1.056,5998,379,310))
```

I expected the code to evaluate the function at i=4000, then i=5000 etc. The output I recieve is as follows;
TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_xor' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

I can't seem to find any specific examples for implementing a conditional function like this. Another attempt was made without a loop but I ran into value errors where I believe I was evaluating arrays as if they were one variable.

I wish to integrate and plot sums of the function later. Will I run into any issues with an approach involving a loop?

Comment: I'm not sure this is the only issue, but I strongly suspect you intend `^2` to be squaring something, which is not what that operator does in Python. You need `**2` instead. Also, defining a function inside a loop is a bit silly, you should define the function just once and call it repeatedly from the loop.

Comment: `^` is not the power operator in python, `**` is. Although you can use `λ` as a variable name it is not recommended. Can you include some input and the expected output?

Answer (score 3):

Python uses `**` for exponentiation. `^` is [bitwise xor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your function is correct apart from the power operator `**`, a possible implementation with `numpy` would look like this

```
# import math                           # does not work well with numpy
import numpy as np

def f(l,a,u,o1,o2):                     # change 'λ' to 'l' (it's easier to type)
    o = np.where(l <= u, o1, o2)        # vectorize piecewise definition
    return a*np.exp((l-u)**2/(-2*o**2)) # change '^' to '**' operator, use np.exp
 
x = np.arange(4000,8000,1000)           # define value range
print(f(x,1.056,5998,379,310))          # call your function one time with entire range
```

Output

```
[9.74560013e-07 3.29586202e-02 1.05597802e+00 5.68878883e-03]
```

To reuse your function you can change it into a parameterized version

```
import numpy as np

def f(a,u,o1,o2):
    return lambda x: a*np.exp((x-u)**2/(-2*np.where(x <= u, o1, o2)**2)) 
 
x = np.arange(4000,8000,1000) 
f_p = f(1.056,5998,379,310)     # parameterize your function
print(f_p(x))                   # call the parameterized function with your value range
```

Output

```
[9.74560013e-07 3.29586202e-02 1.05597802e+00 5.68878883e-03]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import math
import numpy as np

def f(λ,a,u,o1,o2):
    o = o1 if (λ <= u) else o2
   return a*math.exp((λ-u)^2/(-2*o^2))

for i in np.arange(4000,8000,1000):  
  print(f(i,1.056,5998,379,310))
```

Try this code. This will work

Comment: Your indentation is not valid and yields the same error as OP's implementation.